# How can I add data to a firestore array without overwriting it's previous content?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to store book Ids in the books array in firestore. every time I add a new book it overwrites the first one.

```
await updateDoc(
  doc(dataBase, "users", user.uid),
  {
    currentlyReading: {
      arrayUnion(bookId)
    }
  },
  { merge: true }
);
```

I'm using `updateDoc` as stated in the documentation + `merge: true`, but it only stores one element. is there any way I can keep adding elements without overwriting? Thank you in advance.

this is a screen shot of the Document [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{ merge: true }` prevents from existing fields from being removed when using `setDoc()` and doesn't work for array elements. There's no need for that option when using `updateDoc()`. One way would be to use [`arrayUnion()`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) add new elements to the array.

```
import { doc, updateDoc, arrayUnion } from "firebase/firestore"

await updateDoc(doc(dataBase, "users", (user.uid)), {
  currentlyReading:{
    books: arrayUnion(bookId)
  }            
})
```

Comment: Another alternative would be to read the array first, update it locally and then update the modified array in the firestore document.

Comment: @S.Singh yes it is but that'll incur 1 read along with 1 write charge while using `arrayUnion()` will incur 1 write only.

Comment: Even with arrayUnion it keeps overwriting.

Comment: @AbdallahBari can you share your updated code and screenshot of your document that is being updated?

Comment: @Dharmaraj: yes true, but `arrayUnion()` updates only the unique element so indeed if that's what the user wants then it is the best approach.

Comment: @AbdallahBari can you try `"currentlyReading.books": arrayUnion(bookId)`? instead of currentlyReading as object

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, I'm new to stackOverflow. But I wrote it exactly as you sugested. when the books array is empty it works and the book gets added. But it overwrites it the second time around.

Comment: Your sugestion "currentlyReading.books": arrayUnion(bookId) worked perfectly. Thank you so much this was a crucial problem for me.